# How to add two button in grid.mvc in Asp.Net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, grid.mvc, mvcgrid

I have a problem here I am using Grid.MVC I want to add two buttons with the different action links to **View** and **Delete** item.

Here is my code.

```
columns.Add().Titled("Option").Encoded(false)
                        .Sanitized(false)
                        .SetWidth("30%")
                        .RenderValueAs(o => (@<a href="@Url.Action("UserDetails", "Administration", new { id = o.UserID })">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="View" />
                        </a>) (@<a href="@Url.Action("NewInvestment", "Administration", new { id = o.UserID })">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Delete" />
                        </a>));
```

Any one who understand Grid.MVC better. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
columns.Add().Titled("Option").Encoded(false)
                        .Sanitized(false)
                        .SetWidth("30%")
                        .RenderValueAs(o=>(                     
                             Html.ActionLink("View","UserDetails", "Administration", new {id = o.UserID}, new {@class = "btn btn-default"}).ToHtmlString()
                            + Html.ActionLink("Delete","NewInvestment", "Administration", new {id = o.UserID}, new {@class = "btn btn-default"}).ToHtmlString()
                            )
                        );
```